# Android app crashes in emulator but stacktrace and logs are missing

Tags: android, android-studio, android-emulator, stack-trace

I'm playing around with Android development and am following this basic tutorial. I have produced my first Android app ([code is in this repo](https://github.com/hotmeatballsoup/HelloAndroid)) and am having an issue with it crashing inside the emulator and not being able to access the stacktrace or error logs.

When you open the app and click the "**DO IT!**" button:

[image]

...the app crashes and restarts:

[image]

However I can't find any way to access a stacktrace/error logs either from inside the emulator, or from somewhere inside Android Studio, or from somewhere on my file system. **Any idea as to what might be going on and/or where I can access the logs?**

Comment: Select your emulator in connected devices drop-down option in top left logcat window. Or if still this problem occurs restart your emulator.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Intent from Google](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/starting-activity.html),
your intent is null: `Intent intent = new Intent(this, null);`

should be like:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, DisplayMessageActivity.class);
EditText editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);
String message = editText.getText().toString();
intent.putExtra(EXTRA_MESSAGE, message);
startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: Thanks @Thomas Law (+1) - that worked! However, it still leaves me wondering...where do I go to find logs or stacktraces when the app is running in the emulator?

Comment: @smeeb 

click on the android monitor at bottom there, you should found what you wanted, 
[Sample Image](https://i.imgur.com/xbPpCd1.png)